# Jquery ajax - function taking another function response

Tags: jquery, ajax

I've got really annoying situation, when I'm calling multiple ajax requests in my application at the same time (it's neccesary).
My backend response is built like this:

> {"one":{"id":"75068337","value":"1"},"two":{"id":"7449461","value":"1"},"events":[]}

but sometimes "events" object can contain some elements and then it's looking like

> {"one":{"id":"75095540","value":"1","result":"1"},"two":{"id":"7452784","value":"1","result":"1"},"events":{"1531501188":"event 1","1531501405":"event2","1531504270":"event3","1531507336":"event4"}}

And now.. every ajax call is fired depending if checkbox with given ID is checked and it's calling for unique url then on success it's putting response values into  html elements, which are also identified by them ID's.

Main trouble is here: When one of checkbox is checked and his response gives "events" with elements, all other ajax calls are getting them to their html elements.

When I'm checking every response separately by entering ajax.php?id=1-2-3 backend gives me correct response, without any events.

What's wrong with my code?

Ajax:

```js
    var idezy = "1-2-3"; // 1-2 - values needed in backend, 3 - html element ID
    var identifier = "checkbox1"; // ID of checkbox to check if it's checked before calling ajax again

    function bier(idezy, identifier) {
        iczs = idezy.split('-');
        $.ajax({
            url: 'ajax.php?id=' + idezy,
            dataType: "json",
            success: function(results) {
                $.each(results, function(index, value) {
                    if (index == "one") {
                        $('#oneb' + value["id"]).html(value["value"]);
                        $('#onew' + value["id"]).html(value["result"]);
                    }

                    if (index == "two") {
                        $('#twob' + value["id"]).html(value["value"]);
                        $('#twow' + value["id"]).html(value["result"]);
                    }

                    if (index == "events") {
                        $.each(value, function(idx, vale) {
                            $(vale).insertBefore($('table#eventy' + iczs[2] + ' tbody#eventz' + iczs[2] + ' > tr:first'));
                        });
                    }
                });

                if ($("#" + identifier).is(':checked')) {
                    bier(idezy, identifier);
                }
            }
        });
    }
```

```html
<table>
 <tbody>
  <tr>
    <td><input type="checkbox" id="checkbox1"></td>
    <td>
    <table id='eventy1'>
      <thead>
      <th>Event time</th>
      <th>Event desc.</th>
      </thead>
      <tbody id='eventz1'>
      <tr id='dummy'><td>time0</td><td>description0</td></tr>  
      </tbody>
      </table>
    </td>
  </tr>
  
  <tr>
    <td><input type="checkbox" id="checkbox2"></td>
    <td>
    <table id='eventy2'>
      <thead>
      <th>Event time</th>
      <th>Event desc.</th>
      </thead>
      <tbody id='eventz2'>
      <tr id='dummy'><td>time0</td><td>description0</td></tr>  
      </tbody>
      </table>
    </td>
  </tr>
  
  <tr>
    <td><input type="checkbox" id="checkbox3"></td>
    <td>
    <table id='eventy3'>
      <thead>
      <th>Event time</th>
      <th>Event desc.</th>
      </thead>
      <tbody id='eventz3'>
      <tr id='dummy'><td>time0</td><td>description0</td></tr>  
      </tbody>
      </table>
    </td>
  </tr>

 </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Post your HTML, little difficult to debug what's going on without it.

Comment: There is example html: http://jsfiddle.net/2Lqta37m/
Ajax should append new "events" in inner tables if there is any in event response.

Comment: Don't use links to external sites, they have a habit of disappearing are detracting from the value of the question..  Put the HTML in the question please.

Comment: Now the HTML is inserted into my question.

Comment: The code you're showing seems to be the case that works correctly, it's hard to tell since you're not showing how `bier` is originally called.  Please show how you call `bier` when it does not work.

Comment: "bier" is starting when I'm checking the checkbox near inner table with "events" (see html), then it's called in ajax after putting data into html (see ajax)

Comment: I have fixed that and it was absurd.. I have to put my 3 url parameters separately, I was giving "?id=1-2-3" and later exploding it in php to get 1,2,3.
Now ajax working correctly when url parameter is "?id=1&id2=2&id3=3"